# Python extract only part of a table from a PDF file

Tags: python

I have a PDF file and am trying to use tabula to read and extract the table. But I only get a few rows of the table extracted to CSV not the entire table.
Is there anything wrong with the PDF file?

any help would be appreciated!

```
import tabula

from tabula import read_pdf

import pandas as pd

from tabula import read_pdf


tabula.convert_into(r"C:\Users\zjalil\Desktop\CDS_Analytical2.pdf", "CLD.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')
```

Comment: Most PDFs are not really designed to have their data extracted neatly, so tools like this don't always work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = tabula.read_pdf("C:\Users\zjalil\Desktop\CDS_Analytical2.pdf", encoding='utf-8', spreadsheet=True, pages='1-6041')
```

Then save this DataFrame as csv file:

```
df.to_csv('CLD.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: for the second line (df.to_csv..) I get this error :'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: `df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(fl) for fl in df)` then; `df.to_csv('CLD.csv', encoding='utf-8')`